# How to avoid function definition conflict between parent contract and interface

Tags: solidity

Given an interface

```
interface ICat {
  function external lives() external view virtual returns (uint256);
}
```

And a contract

```
contract CatStorage {
  uint256 lives;
}
```

The following contract, inheriting from both, will yield an error:

```
contract Cat is ICat, CatStorage {}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Derived contract must override function "lives". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types.
Since one of the bases defines a public state variable which cannot be overridden, you have to change the inheritance layout or the names of the functions.
```

Is there a way of preventing this without redundantly rewriting the function with an override in the `Cat` contract, without merging the interface and storage contract into an abstract contract?

The use-case for this odd pattern is following a proxy delegation pattern for future upgrades where the proxy and the implementation share the same storage.

Comment: In solidity interfaces are usually used for interacting with an external contract, they aren't used for inheritance that much. Having `contract Cat is CatStorage {}` should work.

Comment: I understand. In this case `lives()` would be an external function I'd want the public to invoke. But, the underlying variable itself I'd want from the storage contract. Hence the question

Comment: You can make the variable public so the compiler will create a public getter with the same name: `uint256 public lives`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing. That's why i'm getting the error - the auto-generated getter clashes with the interface function.

Comment: If you inherit from ICat then you cannot have a variable named `lives`, you can have an external function with the same name. I won't recommend to use interfaces for inheritance.